# How to convert npm-shrinkwrap.json to package-lock.json file?

Tags: npm

I have an old project with `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file.

Now, I want to convert `npm-shrinkwrap.json` to `package-lock.json` file.

How can I do that?

The most important thing is the dependency tree and version must be correct.

Answer (score 7):

As a simple solution, we may just rename file from `npm-shrinkwrap.json` to `package-lock.json` since both the files are meant to have exactly same content and format. Done! Refs [package-lock.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/configuring-npm/package-lock-json) and [npm-shrinkwrap.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/configuring-npm/npm-shrinkwrap-json).

Although both the files have exactly the same content, there are a handful of differences in how npm handles them. For example when we run `npm install` vs `npm ci` commands. Also note that `package-lock.json` will not be published to npm registry unlike `npm-shrinkwrap.json`, if we ever decide to publish our npm package (using `npm publish` command). One may refer official npm docs for detailed info on these specific commands.

Cheers!